# Stimulsoft Report Viewer Localization problem in .net core

Tags: .net-core, report, stimulsoft

I am using the Stimulsoft Report Viewer in my .net core application, and it working fine without any problem until I will add Localization in the StiNetCoreViewerOptions. Viewer Code is like below:

```
@Html.StiNetCoreViewer(new StiNetCoreViewerOptions()
{
    Actions =
    {
        GetReport = "GetReport",
        ViewerEvent = "ViewerEvent"
    },
    Appearance =
    {
        RightToLeft = true,
        ShowTooltips = false,
        ShowTooltipsHelp = false
    },
    Theme = StiViewerTheme.Office2013DarkGrayPurple,
    Localization = "~/Localization/fa.xml"
    //Localization = "Localization/fa.xml" tried this one -> not working
});
```

The problem rise after adding Localization is this :

```
System.FormatException: 'The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.'
```

I read a lot of documentation and checking this [link](https://github.com/stimulsoft/Samples-NET.Core-3.1-MVC-CSharp/tree/master/Localizing%20the%20Viewer), but I am still struggling with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in Stimulsoft.Reports.Ultimate-Designer.2020.2.2 which is throwing an error after I add Localization to the Stimulsoft .netCore Viewer.

By Downgrade Stimulsoft Reports Ultimate Designer to the Version 2020.2.1, You can solve the problem. (or maybe upgrade to next version)